# Function to inverse kron function value

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is there any function or any way to find an inverse value to kron function in MATLAB?

```
matrix = [1 1 -1 ];
code =   [ 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1];
spread_code = kron(matrix,code);
```

after speading i got the following value

```
ans =
  Columns 1 through 15
     1     1     1    -1    -1    -1     1     1     1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  Columns 16 through 18
     1     1     1
```

and now i want to convert the code to it is original value which is `[1 1 -1 ]`
any help please ?

Comment: To clarify, you don't actually mean the "inverse Kronecker product," i.e., `inv(kron(a,b))` (equal to `kron(inv(a),inv(b))` if `a` and `b` are square and non-singular), right? You actually want decompose the output into the two inputs? Can one assume that either `matrix` or `code` is known?

Comment: Could you confirm that you are looking to retrieve the values of `matrix` using `spread_code` and `code`? If so, rather than using the term `inverse`, something like `reversing` or any of it's synonyms might suit I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For vector inputs to `kron`, this would work -

```
spread_code(1:numel(code):end)./code(1)
```

Comment: To vote or not to vote..? 8000 is such a nice round number =)