# How to find the Inverse Kron?

Tags: matlab, matrix

If I know that K = kron ( A , B ),where kron is the Kronecker product of matrices as defined in MATLAB, how can I find A and B from a given matrix K?

for example suppose that

```
K = [1 0 0 0 ;0 1 0 0 ; 0 1 0 0 ;0 1 0 0 ;1 0 0 0 ;0 1 0 0 ;0 1 0 0 ;0 1 0 0 ;1 0 0 0 ;0 1 0 0 ;0 1 0 0 ;0 1 0 0 ;0 0 1 0 ;0 0 0 1 ;0 0 0 1 ;0 0 0 1 ]
```

is there any way to find A and B, such that K = kron ( A , B )?
In this case, A and B are as follows:

```
A = [ 1 0 ; 1 0 ; 1 0 ; 0 1 ]
B = [ 1 0 ; 0 1 ; 0 1 ; 0 1 ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Short Discussion and Solution Code

You can't find both `A` and `B`, given a `K`, because there could be many possible `A`'s and `B`'s to produce a certain `kron` matrix, `K`. Thus, alongwith `K`, you need either `A` or `B` to get the remaining input `B` or `A` respectively.

**Case #1** Given `A` and `K` (kron matrix), you can find `B` with -

```
B = K(1:size(K,1)/size(A,1),1:size(K,2)/size(A,2))./A(1)
```

**Case #2** Given `B` and `K` (kron matrix), you can find `A` with -

```
A = K(1:size(B,1):end,1:size(B,2):end)./B(1)
```

Thus, if not the entire other input, you would at least need to know the size of it and one of the elements of it, preferably the first element.

---

### Function Code

You can very easily convert that to a function code for an easy plug-n-play usage -

```
%// INVERSE_KRON   Inverse of Kronecker tensor product to find one of the inputs.
%   // INVERSE_KRON(K,ARRAY,INPUT_ID) finds one of the inputs used for calculating the
%   // Kronecker tensor product given the other input and the ID of that other input.
%   // Thus, if K was obtained with K = KRON(A,B), one must use -
%       // A = INVERSE_KRON(K,B,2) to find A, and
%       // B = INVERSE_KRON(K,A,1) to find B.

function out = inverse_kron(K,array,input_id)

switch input_id
    case 1
        out = K(1:size(K,1)/size(array,1),1:size(K,2)/size(array,2))./array(1);
    case 2
        out = K(1:size(array,1):end,1:size(array,2):end)./array(1);
    otherwise
        error('The Input ID must be either 1 or 2')
end

return;
```

Typical use case would look like this -

```
K = kron(A,B);          %// Get kron product
A = inverse_kron(K,B,2) %// Recover A
B = inverse_kron(K,A,1) %// Recover B
```

**Note:** For a vector case, one other related question and answer could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23858348/function-to-inverse-kron-function-value/23859196#23859196).